# how to correctly pivot a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, pivot-table

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'answers': ['No'], 'questionId': 'applicationSubmitted'}, {'answers': ['NOT_READY_TO_ENROLL'], 'questionId': 'status'}, {'answers': ['Intro'], 'questionId': 'salesProcessReached'}, {'answers': [True], 'questionId': 'noTimeToCoverCurrentPlan'}, {'answers': [''], 'questionId': 'currentPlan'}, {'answers': ['No'], 'questionId': 'scheduleFollowUp'}])
```

Upon applying pivot function `df.pivot(columns='questionId')` , i get the following table:
[image: Too many extra rows]

How can I tweak the pivot to have only 1 row show up for all answers, with only 1 row for headers instead of two.

Thank you

Comment: Check Q/A no. 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pivot_table` with `aggfunc` as `max`:

```
df.pivot_table(columns='questionId', aggfunc=max)
```

Output:

```
questionId applicationSubmitted currentPlan noTimeToCoverCurrentPlan salesProcessReached scheduleFollowUp                 status
answers                    [No]          []                   [True]             [Intro]             [No]  [NOT_READY_TO_ENROLL]
```